# How to store geo-spatial data in MongoDB with Go driver or mgo/qmgo?

Tags: mongodb, go, geospatial, spatial, mgo

I'm using [MongoDB driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) and [mgo-forked qmgo](https://github.com/qiniu/qmgo) in Go to operate MongoDB (version 5.x).

I have some geo-spatial data to store and query, and searched some articles and someone mentioned to create custom struct `GeoJSON`, others said another custom struct, but it's not official way and not consistent.

Is there any proper ways to store and query such data with Go packages?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you'll want to query this data using geo qualities Mongo [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#geojson-objects) do specify this

> To calculate geometry over an Earth-like sphere, store your location data as GeoJSON objects.

Basically the structure you want to save should match the spatial index requirements, so it should be in this structure:

`<field>: { type: <GeoJSON type> , coordinates: <coordinates> }`

Comment: But how to do that in Go? Official manual or third-party package doesn't mention or provide data structure for GeoJSON type.

Answer (score 0):

A GeoJSON is a complex object to handle in Go since it changes according with the specific type, that could be:

Point
LineString
Polygon
MultiPoint
MultiLineString
MultiPolygon
GeometryCollection

Each one of them has its own implementation, take a look at [GeoJSON Objects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/)

Some implementations of that:

```golang
type Point struct {
    Type        string `json:"type"`
    Coordinates []float64  `json:"coordinates"`
}

type LineStringAndMultipoint struct {
    Type        string  `json:"type"`
    Coordinates [][]float64`json:"coordinates"`
}

type Polygon struct {
    Type        string    `json:"type"`
    Coordinates [][][]float64 `json:"coordinates"`
}

// Alternatively you could create a all-in-one struct using interface as Coordinates

type GeoJSON struct {
    Type        string    `json:"type"`
    Coordinates interface {}`json:"coordinates"`
}
```

Some example using it:

(Example)[https://gist.github.com/Lebski/8f9b5992fec0bf175285f1c13b1e5051]

```golang
insertResult, err := PointCollection.InsertOne(context.TODO(), GeoJSON{Type: "Point", []float64{lat, long}})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Could not insert new Point")
    }
    log.Infof("Inserted new Point. Id: %s\n", insertResult.InsertedID)
```